# Python Crontab user parameter throwing error FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, cron, embedded, scheduled-tasks, iot

(Forgive me if my terminology is off. I'm relatively new to a lot of this stuff.)
I'm developing a system on a Multitech gateway (I don't know if that's relevant) and I need to check-in on a server every 30 minutes. I started looking into task schedulers and Crontab seemed like a good fit. My goal is to have Crontab execute a check-in script at the required interval. But it's throwing the error "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" when I put my PC's username in the user field. This error happens in PyCharm and the gateway. To make sure I was giving it the right username I used the command "whoami" in the command line.

Also, to avoid having to go into the command line of every gateway I setup, I pip installed crontab using the subprocess module. Is this the best way to do this? Since there are so many gateways I'm going to have to load this on to, I want to make the process as simple as uploading the tarballed files and starting the gateway.

Here is the code:

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install',
    'python-crontab'])
except:
    print("Could not install python-crontab")
from crontab import CronTab

cron = CronTab(user = 'username')
job = cron.new(command='python check-in.py', comment='comment')
job.minute.every(30)
cron.write()
```

Constructive criticism is much appreciated as I am very excited about working in this field and would love to master every detail.